# Reading a line from a text file and storing it into a 2D vector in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector, 2d-vector

This is my code, it reads string by string instead of reading a line and stores it in a 1D vector rather than 2D. I want to store each line in the first dimension of the array and then every element within that line in the second dimension of the array.

```
std::ifstream fin("triangulation#4.tri");
std::vector<std::string> vec;

//input from file
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fin), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(vec));
```

Comment: Is this a [jagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) or rectangular array?

Comment: Use `std::getline` to get each line and then create a `std::stringstream` from the line to use your solution above.

Comment: What do you mean by "every element"?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Reading in from a file or creating and putting strings in the 2nd Dimenstion?

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you stuck in reading in lines from a file or how to fill a 2d vector, so I give you both and to not steal you the success of getting things done yourself I leave them seperated (Its not too hard if you have this code since you are learning, so you will remember). That code snippets works well.

This works on Linux to read in a file line by line into a vector.

```c++
string dir = string("."); //dir read for string puzzle
  vector<string> files = vector<string>(); //dir read
      getdir(dir,files);                     //dir read
           for (unsigned int i = 0;i < files.size();i++) //files of parent DIR gets red into array/Vector
           {
             if (files[i].find(filter) != string::npos)   
             {
                               string out = files[i];

             }
           }
```

This is to initialize a 2d vector:

```
vector < vector < size_t > > > _card_deck;
```

And this is a way to fill it with the strings:

```c++
for(size_t playnum = 0; playnum < players; ++playnum)
  {
        vector < vector < size_t > > d1;
        _card_deck.push_back( d1 );

        for(size_t color = 0; color < 4; color++)
            {
            vector < size_t > d2;
                    _card_deck[playnum].push_back( d2 );
            }
   }
```